# Multiple arguments in URL Template Tag

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a couple arguments to my url, if I have only a single argument everything works great. However, if I try to use 2 it converts them to a dict and throws an error. Below are a couple thing that I have tried without success, any help would be awesome. I'm running Django 1.8.4

```
            {% autoescape off %}
            <a href={% url "products.views.display_product_list" page=previous keyword=current_keyword %}>
                Previous</a>
            Current Page
            <a href={% url "products.views.display_product_list" page=next keyword=current_keyword %}>
                Next</a>
            {% endautoescape %}

            <a href={% url "products.views.display_product_list" page=previous,keyword=current_keyword %}>
                Previous</a>
            Current Page
            <a href={% url "products.views.display_product_list" page=next,keyword=current_keyword %}>
                Next</a>
```

The first gives an error of NoReverseMatch at /results/page-0/

While the second is TemplateSyntaxError at /results/page-0/
Could not parse the remainder

My URL looks like:

```
r'^(?:page-(?P<page>[0-9]*)/)(?:keyword-(?P<keyword>[0-9A-Z]*)/)?$'
```

Webpage Traceback:

```
Reverse for 'products.views.display_product_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page': 0, 'keyword': 'dress'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results/(?:page-(?P<page>[0-9]*)/)(?:keyword-(?P<keyword>[0-9A-Z]*)/)?$']

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888/results/page-0/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=CxlgETtyGPQpKa9pG276SZ0zzPQky9JA&keywords=dress
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'products.views.display_product_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page': 0, 'keyword': 'dress'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results/(?:page-(?P<page>[0-9]*)/)(?:keyword-(?P<keyword>[0-9A-Z]*)/)?$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\William\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
```

Comment: The first one is the correct syntax. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @knbk Just added traceback on webpage, nothing on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?P<keyword>[0-9A-Z]*)
```

This part of your regex only matches digits and uppercase letters, but you pass a lowercased word to the `{% url %}` tag. You need to change the pattern accordingly:

```
(?P<keyword>[0-9a-zA-Z]*)
```

Comment: WOW, feeling slow right now. I caught and fixed the Upper scenario but forgot the lower. Thanks!